# identified distinct arrangement of values by groups in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataframe that has as it's primary organization a single row with groups that are all identical length (in the toy example 3).

```
df <- data.frame(groups = c("gr1","gr1","gr1","gr2","gr2","gr2","gr3","gr3","gr3"),
               no = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
               colA = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"),
               colB = c("a", "b", "c", "X_", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"),
               colC = c("a", "b", "c", "X_", "b", "c", "c", "b", "a"))

df

> df
>   groups no colA colB colC
> 1    gr1  1    a    a    a
> 2    gr1  2    b    b    b
> 3    gr1  3    c    c    c
> 4    gr2  1    a   X_   X_
> 5    gr2  2    b    b    b
> 6    gr2  3    c    c    c
> 7    gr3  1    a    a    c
> 8    gr3  2    b    b    b
> 9    gr3  3    c    c    a
```

I want to identify for each column which group is the first example of a unique arrangement of values. So for colA it should return (T, F, F) since all three groups are identical so only group one is the 1st unique on. For colB it should return (T, T, F) since there are two distinct groups and only the 3rd is identical to the 1st. And for colC it should be (T, T, T) since the order of items matters.

So the final output could be a matrix like this

```
       colA  colB  colC
> gr1     T     T     T
> gr2     F     T     T
> gr3     F     F     T
```

I think I could figure this out by breaking down the data frame into pairs of group and colA/B/B, identify which ones are identical, storing the results in a vector, and then reassembling the whole deal. But I am seeing a ton of for-loops and have a hard time thinking about how to vectorize this. I have been using dplyr a bit, but I don't yet see how it can help.

Maybe there's a decent way to unstack each of the columns based on the groups and then run a comparison across the relevant subsets of new (and shorter) columns?

---

Edited to add:

Maybe group_by %>% summarize is a way to get at this. If the summary can essentially concatenate all values in a group per column into a really long string I could then see which of those is distinct per group?

---

Second edit:

I got as far as:

```
d1 <- df %>% group_by(groups) %>% summarise(colB = paste(unique(colB), collapse = ', ')) %>% distinct(colB)
```

which puts out

```
> # A tibble: 2 x 1
>   colB    
>   <chr>   
> 1 a, b, c 
> 2 X_, b, c
```

It identifies the distinct groups, but I now have to figure out how to compare it against the rest full column to get T/F for each group.

Comment: Great catch. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a base R approach :

```
cols <- grep('col', names(df))
cbind(unique(df[1]), sapply(df[cols], function(x) 
      !duplicated(by(x, df$groups, paste0, collapse = '-'))))

#  groups  colA  colB colC
#1    gr1  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
#4    gr2 FALSE  TRUE TRUE
#7    gr3 FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

Comment: Awesome, @Ronak. As always amazingly quick. And another great learning experience. I will start unpacking each part of the nested code to understand which each step actually does.

Answer (score 2):

Your summarize idea is spot on:

```
df %>%
  group_by(groups) %>%
  summarize(across(starts_with("col"), paste, collapse = ""), .groups = "drop") %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("col"), ~!duplicated(.)))
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   groups colA  colB  colC 
#   <chr>  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
# 1 gr1    TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
# 2 gr2    FALSE TRUE  TRUE 
# 3 gr3    FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

Comment: This is truly magic how quickly you guys can figure this out. It'll still take me a while to even understand the line of code. I hope you don't mind that I am giving the 'base R' answer the checkmark, since I think it might be preferred if other folks stumble across the question.

Comment: Yeah, no worries - which answer to accept is purely up to you and Ronak's is excellent as always. If it helps you understand the code, all three answers are identical in methods, just using base/dplyr/data.table. We all `paste` together the columns (though `toString()` saves needing to specify the `collapse` argument for paste - it does that by default), then we all use `!duplicated()` to get the result.

Comment: The `!duplicated()` really is the key. After `unique` and `distinct` it's yet another excellent tool. I'm unfortunately still not there yet. It took me about 20 min to figure out how to replace the `starts_with()` in using a vector with the col names I want to compare (it's `all_of()` I finally figured out). And after all this I got a complete empty table back--which I presume is because all columns are either factors or integers and not characters. So I'll have to convert to character in between somewhere.

Comment: Actually, I guess factors/integers where not the issues but just a simple oversight on my part. :D Working now. Thanks again! 18 groups of 384 rows across about 24 columns neatly reduced to a neat 18x24 table of true or false that I now need to evaluate.

Comment: `all_of()` works with quoted column names, `c()` works with unquoted column names. So you could use `all_of("colA", "colB")` or `c(colA, colB)`.

Comment: The column names were in a vector with each element in the vector being a string. So all_of(col_names) gave me the right results.

Answer (score 2):

With "data.table" you can try:

```
library(data.table)

cols <- c("colA", "colB", "colC")
fun <- function(x) !duplicated(x)
as.data.table(df)[, lapply(.SD, toString), groups, .SDcols = cols][
  , (cols) := lapply(.SD, fun), .SDcols = cols][]
#    groups  colA  colB colC
# 1:    gr1  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
# 2:    gr2 FALSE  TRUE TRUE
# 3:    gr3 FALSE FALSE TRUE
```